# Excel - User Defined Function: [Input - vector], [Output - square matrix with entries on diagonal]

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, udf

How would you write a VBA function in Excel that would turn a vector of input, e.g., "A1" = 1, "B2" = 2, "C3" = 3, into a square matrix with entries on the diagonal, e.g., "E1" = 1, "F1" = 0, "G1" = 0, "E2" = 0, "F2" = 2, "G2" = 0, "E3" = 0, "F3" = 0, "G3" = 3?  Thank you in advance.

I tried to use the following code:

```
Function Test2(X)
  Dim n As Integer
  n = WorksheetFunction.Count(X)
  ReDim Y(1 To n, 1 To n) As Integer
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
  For i = 1 To n
    For j = 1 To n
      If i = j Then Y(i, j) = X(i) Else Y(i, j) = 0
    Next j
  Next i
  Test2 = Y
 End Function
```

I entered the function as an array function, however the output was incorrect.

Comment: What was the input, what was the output, and what was you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I would double check you've entered the function correctly (and make sure you using test2 and not test or something), because it's working for me. Also remember that to properly display an output array, you need to select the entire output range before entering the function and pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This does work:

```
Option Explicit

Function Test2(ByRef x() As Variant) As Variant
  Dim n As Integer
  n = WorksheetFunction.Count(x)
  ReDim y(1 To n, 1 To n) As Variant
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
  For i = 1 To n
    For j = 1 To n
       If i = j Then
        y(i, j) = x(i - 1)
       Else
        y(i, j) = 0
       End If
    Next j
  Next i
  Test2 = y
End Function


Sub checkTest2()
  Dim x() As Variant
  Dim y() As Variant

  x = Array(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2), Cells(3, 3))
  y = Test2(x)

  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
  For i = LBound(y, 1) To UBound(y, 1)
    For j = LBound(y, 2) To UBound(y, 2)
      Cells(i, j).Offset(0,4).Value = y(i, j)
    Next
  Next

End Sub
```